# How to comment line with a specific word

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I'm using sublime text and I need to comment on all the lines that contain the word "set".

For example, I have the following text:

> My dad set up the program.
>
> My name is peter

The result should be:

> #My dad set up the program.
>
> My name is peter

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try anything yet? And what about the word `toolset`, should it trigger the `#` insertion?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have been trying many expressions like "^ # *" ​​but all failed.

Comment: Why did you try to match `#` if you need to search for `set`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex to find:

```
^.*set
```

Replace with: `#$0`

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xpILrr/2)

**EDIT:** Simplified and updated thanks to @Wiktor Stribiżew's suggestions.

Make sure you select 'Regular Expressions' (or Alt + R) while in Replace mode (Ctrl + H)

[image]

Comment: However, it will also detect `set` in `toolset`. And it can be simplified to `^.*set` -> `#$0`. There is no need in a capturing group since the whole match can be referenced to with a 0th group backreference.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew aah yes, that's right. Much simpler! :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Did not know that, great!